# Swift: Understanding Closure Logic

Tags: swift, closures

```swift
import UIKit
func study(reviseNotes: (String) -> Void) {
    print("1")
    let notes = "Napoleon was a short, dead dude."
    print("2")
    for _ in 1...10{
        reviseNotes(notes)
    }
}

study(reviseNotes:{(notes:String) in
    print("3")
    print("I'm reading my notes \(notes)")
})
```

how `reviseNotes(notes)` can call `study( reviseNotes: {(notes:String)} )` ?**
(Prints are for debugging.)

**I'm trying to understand logic?**

Comment: `reviseNotes` is `(String) -> Void`, so it's like a "mini function with a `String` parameter". So when you do `reviseNotes(notes)`, you are telling him to call the method. And `{ (notes:String) in ... }`, that's your implementation of it. It's a closure/callback/block, if you have any other knowledge in coding, or maybe the name might make you understanding it better (`callback` is usually understandable).

Answer (score 0):

`reviseNotes(notes)` is not calling entire `study( reviseNotes: {(notes:String)} )`.
that just trigger parameter what you send, mean only `reviseNotes: {(notes:String)}`

do same process in parts.

```swift
import UIKit
func study(reviseNotes: (String) -> Void) {
    print("1")
    let notes = "Napoleon was a short, dead dude."
    print("2")
    for _ in 1...10{
        reviseNotes(notes)
    }
}

var myClosure = { (notes:String) in
    print("3")
    print("I'm reading my notes \(notes)")
}
study(reviseNotes: myClosure)
```

whenever reviseNotes (10 times inside for loop), will trigger;
it just executes myClosure variable.

In current scenario,
closure get String info, that info can be use inside Body of closure.

some time we need info from closure, whenever we call it.
In that case, closure has a return type other than `Void / ()`.